# How can I add animation before a component re-renders and after it has re-rendered?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have created a simple image slider that has its data stored in an array of objects. Every time I click on the previous/next button the index of the current pointing image changes and a new image and text are shown. I want to add animations before the component re-renders and after it has been rendered. Something like exit and entry of an element but in this case only state I am not removing or adding any new element, I am just changing the state of the component.

```
function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const title = document.querySelector(".title");
    const desc = document.querySelector(".desc");
    desc.classList.remove("desc");
    title.classList.remove("reverse");
    title.classList.remove("title");
    title.clientTop;
    desc.classList.add("desc");
    title.classList.add("title");
  }, [index]);
  return (
    <div className="w-[100vw] h-[100vh] bg-slate-700 flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className="w-[60%] h-[50%] relative bg-gray-500 rounded-md">
        <div className="w-full h-full">
          <img
            src={details[index].image}
            alt="image"
            className="transition-transform max-h-full w-full rounded-md brightness-50"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="absolute top-0 w-full h-full flex flex-row m-2 px-5 gap-5 items-center">
          <Button dir="left" index={index} setIndex={setIndex} />
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
            <h3 className="title text-3xl text-white aboslute transition-transform translate-x-4">
              {details[index].title}
            </h3>
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-start gap-3">
              <Tag tag={details[index].year} />
              <Tag tag="R" />
              <Tag tag="SUB" />
            </div>
            <div className="desc text-md text-white pr-56">
              {details[index].description}
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button dir="right" index={index} setIndex={setIndex} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const Button = ({dir, index, setIndex}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const title = document.querySelector(".title");
    title.classList.add("reverse");

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (dir === "right") {
        if (index === 4) setIndex(0);
        else setIndex((curr) => curr + 1);
      } else {
        if (index === 0) setIndex(4);
        else setIndex((curr) => curr - 1);
      }
    }, 350);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="text-white text-3xl cursor-pointer 
     "
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <div className="rounded-full w-10 h-10 text-center hover:bg-white hover:bg-opacity-25">
        {dir === "left" ? <>&lt;</> : <>&gt;</>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have added animation before a render takes place by using the timeout function and for the case where the component has been rendered, I have used useEffect. I want to know whether there exists an optimal way to perform those actions. Any blog, videos, or articles are appreciated.

Comment: It’s not entirely clear from the description why you need to manipulate animations in the render cycle; not only is it difficult, it’s also extremely bad for performance. Use CSS animations assigned to some class that you can attach to any element at any time, for example, on the active slide when it becomes/stops being active, and let the engine decide when to draw it. If you need to get into the rendering cycle from the moment of assignment, then you can use requestAnimationFrame. Perhaps I did not understand the question)

Comment: Think of having a div with dynamic data inside of it and every time the user clicks on the button the data inside changes causing the component to re-render (as the data is stored inside a state). What I want is to animate the div before data changes like fading out and when it has been rendered again I want it to have to fade in.